# Referencing answers in question space

Tags: discussion, comments, questions, edits

I recently asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264161/minecraft-agrarian-skies-world-seed?noredirect=1#comment369863_264161).

After receiving 2 good answers I was torn between which one to pick. 
One answers my question directly, but the other was more useful to me. (that could possible be it's own meta topic, but we won't go into that now).

Deciding that they were both good answers, I chose to accept the one that was most appropriate to me and edited my question to include clarification on why I did that. See [this revision](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/264161/3).
This was so that anyone else that viewed my question had access to the same information as me (I tested both, both worked for different reasons).

However, this was quickly [rolled back](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/264161/4) and I was told

> The question space isn't meant to be used to comment on answers. You can comment on the answers themselves, but don't use the question space for that purpose

I often hear that comments are "short lived" but i'm not totally sure what people mean by that.

I could have commented on both of these answers the 2 separate points, but then someone with my question has to read both answers and all comments to find what they needed, in oppose to my question and then straight to the answer they wanted.

The fact that it was rolled back makes me think that there was something particularly bad about it, instead of just a "probably should do that".

Why is it incorrect to reference answers in the question if it will save someone else the time of having to read through all answers and comments?

Comment: Is there a reason you came here instead of addressing this on the child meta of Arqade? They may have specific policies there that don't relate to the rest of SE.

Comment: Only because I thought meta Arqade was for Arqade specific discussion. I thought this was a general discussion about all Stack exchange sites. I didn't realise different Stack Exchange sites had different rules about this sort of thing. Should it be migrated?

Comment: You asked it in a general enough way that it is certainly answerable here.... it's not off topic, I would think... The only reason I asked is that you might get a more direct answer there as this strictly relates to a question on Arqade. We get lots of questions here that are, essentially, veiled complaints about why stuff was reverted or edited or why mods did X, or blah, blah, blah... You didn't do that, which is nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as I often wish to understand [why some answers get accepted over others](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34700/removal-of-background-noise-in-movie-scenes/), explaining really isn't necessary.

The check mark is your way as the asker of denoting which answer worked for you, which solution you used for your problem. It does not mean that it's the **best** answer or the answer that will work the best for everyone.

That being said, it's definitely admirable that you want to explain why you opted for one answer over another, particularly when both solutions are valid, if different.

Your worries about comments are understandable... yes, comments should not be **expected** to be permanent... but they are until a mod (or the author) feels they are no longer germane or useful to the topic. They won't ever be automatically deleted by the system.

When people warn you that comments aren't permanent, they mean "if this comment chain gets out of hand, don't expect to find the comments here if a Mod determines they're useless" or "don't complain if someone deletes your comments because you shouldn't expect them to be permanent".

I found this out early on in my SE life and had a nice email chat with one of the SE Community Managers and he explained why my comment had been deleted (by him).

So, the person who reverted your edit was correct to do so and their comment encouraging you to make those notes as comments on the answers was correct as well.

That type of comment is exactly the sort that will likely never be deleted because they are useful and explain the thought process behind why you opted for one answer over the other but encourage users to note that both answers are valid... as opposed to my comment, which did none of those things.

---

As to why adding that context to your question is bad... Questions are for questions. The only content that should be added to them is clarifications of the question - these often help people provide better answers or narrow the scope.

Realistically, (at this point) there are only two answers and four comments on that question, so I'm not really sure that it's saving anyone any time. People really looking for a solution to this issue are going to want to read them both... And they may not even read that far through your question to get to your note... many people read the first few lines of a question to see if it's the same issue they're having and, if it is, they skip to the answers. It's possible they'll be more likely to see your note in the comments than they were to see it in the question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. That makes sense. I guess you're right, people don't read all the question (thinking about it, I don't read the question *at all* on SO).
I will add a comment to both answers. You're right that there are only 2 answers, so it isn't really saving anyone time, I was just trying to more generally understand it.